Calculated field in a pivot table based on power query
I have a sheet with Planned sales data. I have a second sheet with Actual Sales data.
I combined the two sheets using Power Query,
I then created a pivot table but as the data is coming from a model i don't seem to be able to create a pivot table calculated field.
Is there a way to do this?
I am happy to try Power Pivot but I have never used it.
If I have to go the power pivot way, can anybody link me to a how to article or youtube on what i am wanting to do?
Cheers
